# Как из результата SQL-запроса перенести в переменную?

Tags: php, sql

SQL-запрос считает сумму полей у определенного пользователя..

В phpMyAdmin результат такой:

```
SUM(square)
512
```

Скрипт

```
$s = "SELECT SUM(square)  FROM reports WHERE username = '$str';";
$r =  mysql_query($s);
if ($r) {
    echo 'Запрос выполнен' ."<br />" ;
    $Result = mysql_fetch_array($r);
    $user = $Result[SUM(square)];
    echo $user;
}
```

Как правильно вывести результат этого запроса?

Comment: вопрос закрыт

Answer (score 4):

Используйте алиас в запросе:
    SELECT SUM(square) as sm FROM ...

Этот алиас и используйте для ссылки на столбец.

Comment: Или же, раз уж всё равно используется mysql_fetch_array(), то:

   $user = $Result[0];

Comment: Photon, конечно, можно использовать и нумерованный массив, но я ответил на ошибку в использовании ассоциативного.